# string was not recognized as a valid Boolean, when storing 1 or 0 in a bit field

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a column inside Sql Server2008 r2 with a type "Bit". but when I tried to manually add data to the table by entering 0 or 1 . I get the following error:-
"**string was not recognized as a valid Boolean**"

Comment: Please refer http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/330293/1-and-0-not-recognised-as-boolean#details

Answer (score 0):

If I type True OR False it will work well.